# Successor cardinals independent of ZF

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals

I heard recently that for a given cardinal $\lambda$, the fact that there is a least cardinal $\lambda^+$ greater than $\lambda$ is independent of ZF... Is this true? And if so, is it possible to show why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by 'cardinal'. If 'cardinal' means 'initial ordinal', the answer is no:

Let $X$ be any set (e.g. $X$ can be a cardinal). Hartogs' number of $X$, given by
$$
\aleph(X) := \{ \beta \in \mathrm{Ord} \mid \text{ there is some injection } \beta \to X \}
$$
is the least ordinal which cannot be embedded into $X$. If $X$ itself was an initial ordinal (a cardinal), then $\aleph(X)$ is precisely the cardinal successor of $X$.

On the other hand, if you allow for non-wellorderable cardinals $X$, it's not obvious what its cardinal successor would even mean. (You could reasonably argue that it should be the Hartogs' number of $X$ -- which always exists but maybe you have something else in mind).

Comment: Really? Assuming AD you would say that $\aleph_1$ is $\frak c^+$?

Comment: I was talking about initial ordinals, thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I didn't say any such thing. I only said that you could argue this to be the case. If you want the notions of cardinal successors to be defined in $\mathrm{ZF}$, Hartog's number seems like a reasonable choice to me. Personally, I'd probably leave it undefined for non-wellorderable cardinals.

Comment: The notation, by the way, of $X^+$ is abhorrent.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have no idea whether it's standard -- but it's the notation I've been taught when I first learned about Hartog's numbers. Since I mainly work with choice, it doesn't strike me as bad but I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: (1) It is awful. (2) $\aleph(X)$ would be a standard notation. (3) This is the problem that people doing AD-stuff don't give a crap on other AC research, so there is a metric ton of overlapping and contradicting notations. (4) Hartogs', not Hartog's.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, I always thought his name was 'Hartog' -- thanks! I'll change the notation in my post as well.

Comment: By the way, you don't need $\sup$ in the definition. (And removing it will make it work for finite $X$ too).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point, thanks!